# Appending to a URL

Tags: javascript, url, append

Hi i'm trying to append two new query parameters, lets say `'hello=true&voice=hello'`, to a `url` only if a function, lets say `disable()` comes back `true`.

if there no better way of writing this than this append method? Is there a way to simplify this?

```
disable() === true ? url.searchParams.append('hello', 'true') : url
disable() === true ? url.searchParams.append('voice', 'hello') : url
```

I tried concatenation, but i'm getting an **Unexpected string concatenation** error with this

```
 const urlNew = disable() === true ? url + '?hello=true&voice=hello' : url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals like this:

```
const urlNew = disable() === true ? `${url}?hello=true&voice=hello` : url;
```